# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ereg() PHP y MySql

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, function, localhost

Estoy revisando un proyecto en local con Xampp y esta mostrando un error al hacer el llamado de una función de conversión de fecha generando el siguiente mensaje:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ereg() in
> D:\xampp\htdocsD:\xampp\htdocs\rutadelarchivo\lib\tools.php:240 Stack
> trace: #0
> D:\xampp\htdocsD:\xampp\htdocs\rutadelarchivo\admin\agenda\admin.php(99):
> cambiaf_a_mysql('12/07/2022') #1 {main} thrown in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\rutadelarchivo\lib\tools.php on line 240

Al buscar el código del archivo tools.php en la línea 240 la función está así.

```
function cambiaf_a_mysql($fecha){ 
               
    ereg("([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{2,4})", $fecha, $mifecha); 
  $lafecha=$mifecha[3]."-".$mifecha[2]."-".$mifecha[1]; 
  return $lafecha; 

}
```

mientras que admin.php está así en su línea 99:

```
  $t_date = date("Y-m-d");
$t_date_j = date("Y,m-1,d");
if (isset($_GET['t_date']) && $_GET['t_date'] <> "") {
    $t_date = cambiaf_a_mysql($_GET['t_date']);
    $arr_f = explode("-", $t_date);
    $t_date_j = $arr_f[0] . "," . $arr_f[1] . "-1," . $arr_f[2];
}
```

con sus respectivos include:

```
 <?php require_once('../../lib/tools.php'); ?>
```

lo extraño del asunto es que:

1. en el sitio de producción la función esta funcionando bien.
2. en el código que tengo local en el mismo archivo de tools.php hay otra función de fechas que si funciona correctamente.

Aclaro que el código no es mío solo estoy revisándolo para hacer unos ajustes por lo que no sé que más revisarle a esa función para que funcione igual en local que en producción.

Comment: La función [ereg()](http://php.adamharvey.name/manual/es/function.ereg.php) está obsoleta y eliminada desde PHP 7; ahora debes usar [preg_match()](http://php.adamharvey.name/manual/es/function.preg-match.php).

Comment: O puedes usar [mb_ereg()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-ereg.php) en su lugar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dijeron en el comentario, esa función está obsoleta a partir de PHP 5.3 y retirada en 7.0.

La función `cambiaf_a_mysql()` convierte una fecha `'dd/mm/yyyy'` a `'yyyy-mm-dd'`

Entonces esa función la puedes reescribir a esto:

```
function cambiaf_a_mysql($fecha){ 
    $date = explode('/', $fecha);
    return $date[2].'-'.$date[1].'-'.$date[0];
}
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, no siempre es necesario usar expresiones regulares.